# Android Intent through jar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have development one Android Application which has one UI design (like user name,password) i converted my Application into jar(it means i convert my application as library project) after i got the Jar.i used in another application i follow this method

**1.** I added my jar into Reference library path 
**2.** I include the jar in library path 
**3.** I added my jar in Android manifest file like :
         `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>`(which in jar file)

**4.** In my src of my second Application i include my jar ,and also using intent to call my previous application

i call my jar using intent like

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, com.example.testapp.MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(i);
```

but i got the following error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.tui.com/com.example.testapp.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

but i already declare my activity in Android manifest file, i hope i did every thing correct,but i dnt know why i geeting this error

any one know how to access jar using intent in android

Comment: If the application with the Android Manifest does not share the package name with the jar declare the activity with complete package name i.e. com.example.testapp.MainActivity and not just .MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Actually you added your activity in manifest as .MainActivity

and absolute path become yourpackagename.MainActivity

add like com.tui.com.com.example.testapp.MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<activity android:name="com.example.testapp.MainActivity"></activity>
```

Not

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
```