# Android JAVA: Running a JAR file with a MainActivity (Intent Function)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

noob here looking for some help.

I'm using Eclipse for my Android Application and Bluestacks for the virtual machine.

I have created an quick Android Application Project with a button. Below is the code of my button:

```
public void doSomething(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, com.viva.demo.MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

    /*Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.wodota.test123", "com.viva.demo.MainActivity.class");*/
}
```

Below is my code for the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wodota.test123"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.viva.demo.MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've included an activity in my manifest file "com.viva.demo.MainActivity".
Also in my project, I've included the JAR file.

Below is my logcat:

```
08-20 11:47:33.767: D/AndroidRuntime(8573): Shutting down VM
08-20 11:47:33.767: W/dalvikvm(8573): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2cd0180)
08-20 11:47:33.767: I/Process(8573): Sending signal. PID: 8573 SIG: 9
08-20 11:47:33.767: D/AndroidRuntime(8573): procName from cmdline: com.wodota.test123
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.wodota.test123
08-20 11:47:33.767: D/AndroidRuntime(8573): file written successfully with content: com.wodota.test123 StringBuffer : ;com.wodota.test123
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     ... 11 more
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.viva.demo.MainActivity
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     at com.wodota.test123.MainActivity.doSomething(MainActivity.java:24)
08-20 11:47:33.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8573):     ... 14 more
08-20 12:37:45.407: D/AndroidRuntime(9743): Shutting down VM
```

My application just crashes. I think there is a problem in my manifest file. Below is the tutorial that I got for the Intent Function and is working:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qurvm-E9AiU

Please help.

Comment: do you have the jar inside the libs/ folder?

Comment: The MainActivity is your launch activity. Then where is the doSomething() method located?
Secondly in your manifest u have already defined one activity `.MainActivity` and right below it u have put  
`<activity android:name="com.viva.demo.MainActivity" />` , Do you have two Class files with MainActivity as the name?

Comment: user1940676 - no i don't. its in the referenced libraries.

deb - where do I put the second activity? I look at the other questions in stackoverflow and it seems that I need to input another activity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397990/android-intent-through-jar

Comment: The JAR file has a MainActivity. So does my Test Project so that's why I included the com.viva.demo.mainactivity.